# Pure alpha gradient

Tags: materials, transparency

Why don't my gradients fade to pure alpha transparent? Hopefully it's possible. Have a look at my examples and node setup. [image: Bunch of simple shaders, all need gradient to alpha]

[image: This is the shader for the farthest right ring for example]

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You need to use the alpha output of the Color ramp as the factor for the mix shader.  The color output does not cary the alpha information.